# Apache POI get the list of word document revisions

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, docx

I have a 2 documents 1 original and 1 edited, and then I compared them to determine those changes made.
How can I get the revisions/changes as array/list?

[image: edited_pic]

Answer (score 0):

Use RevisionMarkAuthorTable

```
getRevisionMarkAuthorTable()
```

Gets a reference to the revision mark author table, which holds the revision mark authors for the document.

Comment: I tried this already, it only retrieves the Author names. and the list has only 2 entries. 1 Unkwon and the 1 name of author.